# Page numbers only half printed in scrreprt

Tags: positioning, page-numbering, koma-script

I just made a printout of my document in `scrreprt`. I went to a copy shop to see, if everything worked out. Unfortunately, the page numbers are printed only half (the bottom part is cut off). I asked the owner of the shop what was the problem, as the pages are visible on the actual pdf, as for example on page 8:

[image]

The owner told me that the printer adds margins like 5mm, which cut off the bottom. It can be set to scale accordingly, but then my own set margins would not be 100% correct anymore.

My question is, what can be done in Latex to account for this? Maybe raising the numbers a bit? If that's an option, it would have to be possible without changing anything else with regards to format or positioning. My document is very much finalized. Any help is highly appreciated.

part of my preamble (let me know if you wanna see the full thing)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small, numbers=noendperiod]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage[a4paper,]{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
```

Or is it normal to let the printer do the final 'scaling'? Answer: No. I checked the scaled printout's margins which were a little bit too big (eg 2.3 cm on top instead of 2 etc.)

Edit: still looking for a simple solution which does as few as possible to the final document. 'Only' move up the page numbers a bit.

Comment: [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is best to use for this. However, instead of merely setting the margins, consider the options `includefoot` as well, which should set the bottom of the footer to be (say) `2cm` from the bottom of the page boundary. See the [`geometry` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) for more.

Comment: @Werner I read in the documentation on page 3, that includefoot
results in shorter textheight. That's a problem because I cannot really shorten the text anymore ;)

Comment: Then request (from the printer) that they use larger stock... something has to budge it seems.

Comment: I will have to do that if there is no other solution. I was only wondering if there is no way to move all pagenumbers up by an arbitrary value.

Comment: There is certainly a value to move the footer up a bit (footskip or something like this). Check the documentation of geometry. Beside this: the source of the problem are your margins. They are too small.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have just read it. I tried to use Werner's suggestion, but the total layout changed (text didn't fit on pages anymore, so new pages were started etc.). I am not very optimistic in this case :(

Comment: With [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) it may be as simple as `\fancyfoot[C]{\smash{\raisebox{<len>}{\thepage}}}` (you specify `<len>`) to raise the page number under `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: Thanks Werner I will try that too. The only thing I am worrying about is that anything else might change with `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Why don't you simply change footskip as I suggested? A simple search in the documentation shows that this what you want.

Comment: I have just tried `\fancyfoot[C]{\smash{\raisebox{<len>}{\thepage}}}` and changed `<len>`, but it did not change anything. @UlrikeFischer change how? I feel bad to say that, but I am running out of time. I had a look at `geometry` and found nothing just to change just the page position.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if I just change `footskip` to any positive value, that puts it up very high, straight below the footline. So this is too much. Even if I reduce the value to 1mm this is happening.

Comment: Please do not use `geometry` with KOMA-script: KOMA has it's own much superior algorithm for page layouts. Just use the global option `pagesize`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I would like to follow your tip, but I have written my document with these settings and I need to hand in very soon, so I would like to stick with it if possible. If KOMA can achieve the same layout with different settings it would be ok to me.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so what *seems* to be the solution under geometry is the following:

`\geometry{left=2cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,foot=1.7cm}` or more compact `foot = <len>` does the job.

I have checked the pages and everything seems to stay the same, besides the page number moving. Note that `<len>` is measured from the upper beginning of the bottom margin downwards, that's why 1.7 cm looks like a rather high value, but it's not when the lower margin is just 2 cm.